# The Refresh feature in windows 8 is present in any other previous versions of windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8

Many of my users facing repeated issues with Windows 7 OS.
As a sys admin I cannot fix all those errors everytime.
I came across "Refresh without affecting files" feature in windows 8.
But I cannot find the same feature in windows 7, as all my organization systems were installed with windows 7.

Any suggestions for me guys......

Answer (score 2):

This is a [new feature of Windows 8](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/restore-refresh-reset-pc), which is not available in Windows 7. [Microsoft explained the feature](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2012/01/04/refresh-and-reset-your-pc.aspx) and its development history in their MSDN blog.

Explain your real issue, so that we can fix this. See [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).